# Data from the server is not defined : reference error

Tags: javascript, callback

I have the following code scenario, where I am getting some data from the server and I am displaying the data according different session criteria, however it trows me a `Reference error ajProductDataFromServer is not defined in showProduct`.

Seems like `showProduct` does not has a reference to the data, but I can´t figure out where is the gap, please help me! In `getAjax` I am passing the `ajDataFromServer` to the callback, which is `getProductData` in this case. Shouldn´t then `showProduct` be able to access that data as well ?

```
// GLOBAL ARRAY for storing any DATA from the SERVER
var ajDataFromServer = [];

// Main ajax function using callback for getting data from the server
function getAjax(sUrl, callback) {
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      ajDataFromServer = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      callback(ajDataFromServer);
    }
  }

  ajax.open("GET", sUrl, true);
  ajax.send();

}

/************************************************************************/

// INITIALIZE / populate home page with products
document.addEventListener("load", function() {
  getAjax("api_get_products.php", getProductData);
});
getProductData();

/************************************************************************/
// GET ALL PRODUCTS and display them with diffrent features according role
function getProductData(ajProductDataFromServer) {

  if (sSessionRole === "admin") {
    //console.log( "PRODUCTS ARE EDITABLE" );
    showProductAdmin();

  } else if (sSessionRole === "user") {
    //console.log( "PRODUCTS ARE AVAILABLE FOR USER" );
    showProduct();

  } else {
    //console.log( "PRODUCTS AVAILABLE FOR PUBLIC" );
    showProduct();
  }
}

/************************************************************************/

// DISPLAY PRODUCTS for USER / PUBLIC dinamically using a loop and then INSERT into HTML
function showProduct() {
  lblProductList.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < ajProductDataFromServer.length; i++) {

    var lblProduct = '<div class ="lblProduct">' + '<a href="#' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '<img src="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '" width="85%" class="lblProductImage" alt="product">' + '</a>' + '<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '<img src="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '</a>' + '<h3 class ="lblProductName">' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].name + '</h3>' + '<h3 class ="lblProductPrice">' + 'Price:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].price + '<h3 class ="lblProductQuantity">' + 'Quantity:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity + '</h3>' + '<button class="btnBuyProduct" data-productId="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].id + '" >' + 'BUY PRODUCT' + '</button>' + '</div>';

    lblProductList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', lblProduct);
  }

}
```

Comment: What is `getProductData();` supposed to do? You're not passing a parameter, so it will be `undefined`.

Comment: it should invoke the function but I am not sure if  `document.addEventListener("load", function() {
  getAjax("api_get_products.php", getProductData);
});` does basically the same so I might not need to call `getProductData();`? but if I uncomment it then I get no errors but niether data ( products ) displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems.

First, you're calling `getProductData();` outside the `getAjax()` call, so it's running before the AJAX has completed. You're also calling it with no argument, so `ajProductDataFromServer` will be `undefined`. I'm not sure why you have that, it should probably be removed.

Second, `showProduct()` is trying to use the variable `ajProductDataFromServer`, but this is a local variable in `getProductData()`. You need to pass it as an argument:

```
function getProductData(ajProductDataFromServer) {

  if (sSessionRole === "admin") {
    //console.log( "PRODUCTS ARE EDITABLE" );
    showProductAdmin(ajProductDataFromServer);

  } else if (sSessionRole === "user") {
    //console.log( "PRODUCTS ARE AVAILABLE FOR USER" );
    showProduct(ajProductDataFromServer);

  } else {
    //console.log( "PRODUCTS AVAILABLE FOR PUBLIC" );
    showProduct(ajProductDataFromServer);
  }
}

function showProduct(ajProductDataFromServer) {
  lblProductList.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < ajProductDataFromServer.length; i++) {

    var lblProduct = '<div class ="lblProduct">' + '<a href="#' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '<img src="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '" width="85%" class="lblProductImage" alt="product">' + '</a>' + '<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '<img src="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '</a>' + '<h3 class ="lblProductName">' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].name + '</h3>' + '<h3 class ="lblProductPrice">' + 'Price:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].price + '<h3 class ="lblProductQuantity">' + 'Quantity:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity + '</h3>' + '<button class="btnBuyProduct" data-productId="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].id + '" >' + 'BUY PRODUCT' + '</button>' + '</div>';

    lblProductList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', lblProduct);
  }

}
```

Comment: By removing  `getProductData();` and passing `ajProductDataFromServer` as an argument and a parameter to `showProduct();` I don´t get the error but products does not display. Are you sure 
`document.addEventListener("load", function() {
  getAjax("api_get_products.php", getProductData);
});` initializes my products from the server?

Comment: It should be `window.addEventListener("load", ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

In `getProductData` you declare a variable called `ajProductDataFromServer` as an argument name.

That makes it a local variable in the scope of the `getProductData` function.

You never use that variable inside that function.

Meanwhile:

Inside `showProduct`, you attempt (several times) to read data from a variable called `ajProductDataFromServer` but you haven't declared one.

The only `ajProductDataFromServer` variable exists in a different function.

`showProduct` won't have access to `getProductData` variables just because the call to `showProduct` was inside `getProductData`.

You need to pass the data explicitly.

---

As an aside, `getProductData` gets called twice. Once as a callback to the Ajax and once immediately after you add the event listener.

`getProductData();` calls it with no arguments so that time `ajProductDataFromServer` will be `undefined` anyway.